# Laravel 5 execute aggregation with mongodb on where clause

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

[Laravel 5 Eloquent sum of multiplied columns for mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352305/laravel-5-eloquent-sum-of-multiplied-columns-for-mongo-db)

This was my previous question and it got solved with the help of @Alex, now i need to add a where clause of `$field != '0'`

Here I am stuck I tried with the match but still I have no option left to get help from here.

Thanks

Comment: What is `$field`, it's not defined in your original mongo document schema?

Comment: i have tried $ne but not able to understand where do i have to implement

Comment: @chridam its an example i.e amountdue != 0

Answer (score 2):

Using the aggregation pipeline where the **[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)** comparison query operator is in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline:

```
DB::connection($this->MongoSchemaName)
    ->collection($this->InvoicesTable)
    ->raw(function($collection) use ($customer){
        return $collection->aggregate([
            ['$match' => [
                    'ContactID' => (int)$customer->ContactID,
                    'Type' => 'PAYMENT',
                    'AmountDue' => [ '$ne' => 0 ]
                ]
            ],
            ['$group' => [
                '_id' => '$ContactID',
                'TotalInBaseCurrency' => [
                        '$sum' => ['$multiply' => ['$Total', '$CurrencyRate']]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    })
```