# Why sum big data does not work? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, limit, eloquent

My code, you can see this below :

```
public function total()
{
    $query = User::limit(100000)->get();
    $total = $query->sum('total');
    dd($total);
}
```

The result of `dd($total)` not display or empty

But when I change `limit(50000)`, it display the result

Why it does not work if `limit(100000)`?

Note :

In firefox browser, it does not display anything

In chrome browser, it display error :

> This page isn’t working
>
> myshop.dev is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500

Comment: Check `laravel.log` for error message

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, In `laravel.log` does not display an error. Look at my question. I had update it

Comment: Looks like server can't handle all the data at once. Consider chunking results: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#chunking-results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `get`, you are fetching all this records from the database. And then performing the sum with php. You are probably having a timeout when fetching that much records from the database.

Why don't you perform the sum in the database, and then fetch the result?

```
public function total()
{
    $total = User::limit(100000)->sum('total');
    dd($total);
}
```

----- edit -----

When you perform:

`$query = User::limit(100000)->get();`

The `$query` variable actually holds the result set of the query `select * from user limit 100000`. The result set its a collection [(see 
 collect)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections), then you are performing a `sum` on the server-side, something equivalent to:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($user in $query) {
    $sum = $sum + $user->total;
}
```

It's better to perform the sum in the database using the proper aggregate function.

`$total = User::limit(100000)->sum('total');` would translate to:

`select SUM(total) from user limit 1000000`

If the result is 0, probably all your result set for the column `total` is actually 0.

Comment: What field property are you trying to sum?

Comment: I use mongodb. Seems data type of field total is string

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352305/laravel-5-eloquent-sum-of-multiplied-columns-for-mongo-db

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot